# Ionic check multiple Promises are finished

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I want to run multiple promises and print the result if all promises are finished. Currently I try below approach:

```
for (let p of this.invoiceProduct) {
  this.promotionSvc.checkPromoBuyNGetN(this.username, p).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    this.promoBuyNGetNData.push(result);
  })
}

Promise.all(this.promoBuyNGetNData).then(values => {
  console.log(values);
})
```

In the console, it prints `[]` for `console.log(values)` and `{id: "e620c8a8-dca8-11e7-8443-2c56dcbcb038", productIdGet: "98926f8c-6afb-11e7-8dd4-2c56dcbcb038", productGet: "Style Laki", getN: 1, description: ""}` for `console.log(result)`.

From above result we can see that the `Promise.all` doesn't work. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to be trying to push the results of the promises in the array and then calling `Promise.all`.

`Promise.all` takes an array of promise objects and calls all of them and then fires `then` on completion of all promises. YOu can do:

```
promoData:any[]=[];//class variable

for (let p of this.invoiceProduct) {
  this.promoBuyNGetNData.push(this.promotionSvc.checkPromoBuyNGetN(this.username, p));//push the promise function into array
}

Promise.all(this.promoBuyNGetNData).then(values => {
  console.log(values);// all results within values array
  this.promoData=values;
})
```

And in your HTML,

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of promoData">
```

Comment: Hi, how about if I want to display  the result in HTML after the promises are finished? Currently I did `<tr *ngFor="let p of promoBuyNGetNData">`, but it  shows `Promise`.

Comment: you are traversing the array of promises or array of results from `then`?

Comment: My code is the same as your answer. I called the method that executes the code above in ngOnInit.

Comment: you should traverse values.. or use async for each object.. check my updated answer

Comment: It doesn't work, I believe it's because it renders the HTML without waiting for the Promises.

Comment: remember to set it as an empty class array initially..`promoData:any[]=[];//class variable`

Comment: Yes, did that already.. anyway it's a different problem.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

`Promise.all` expects an array of promises. You need to change your for loop to put the promises into `this.promoBuyNGetNData`.  If I understand you correctly, this code should do what you want.

```
for (let p of this.invoiceProduct) {
  const promise = this.promotionSvc.checkPromoBuyNGetN(this.username, p);
  promise.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
  this.promoBuyNGetNData.push(promise);
}

Promise.all(this.promoBuyNGetNData).then(values => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

You can make this cleaner by getting rid of the `promise.then` console log, and turning the for loop into a map.

```
this.promoBuyNGetNData = this.invoiceProduct.map(p => this.promotionSvc.checkPromoBuyNGetN(this.username, p));
Promise.all(this.promoBuyNGetNData).then(values => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

Comment: Yeah.. personally.. think map is cleaner/terse than a traditional for loop.. +1